# Initial value problem differential equation $y' = (x-1)(y-2)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' = (x-1)(y-2)$$
$y(2)= 4$

$$\frac{1}{y-2}dy = (x-1)dx$$

$$\int \frac{1}{y-2}dy =\int (x-1)dx$$

$$\ln(y-2) = \frac{x^2}{2} - x + c$$

$$y - 2 = e^{\frac{x^2}{2} - x + c} $$

$$y = e^{\frac{x^2}{2} - x + c} + 2$$

plug in the inital value

$$y = e^{\frac{2^2}{2} - 2 + c} + 2$$

$$y = e^c+ 2$$

I feel like this is wrong anyways, so where did I go wrong?

Comment: In my experience, when we get a log, and intend to exponentiate, it is better to deal with the initial condition **at the log stage.**

Answer (score 2):

For $x=2$ we have $y=4$ so $e^c=4-2=2$ and finally
$$y = 2e^{\frac{x^2}{2} - x } + 2$$

Answer (score 2):

It would be a good remark that in the step you wrote:

$$\ln(y-2)=x^2/2-x+c$$ we inserted this strong point: $$\ln|y-2|=x^2/2-x+c, ~~y\neq 2$$

Now, if we assume to find just one solution and having $y>2$, then $$y=\exp(x^2/2-x+c)+2=C\exp(x^2/2-x)+2$$ and therefore when $x=2$ then $y=4$ makes the latter equality:

$$4=C\exp(2-2)+2\longrightarrow C=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your last step:

$$
y = e^c + 2 = 4\\
\Rightarrow c = \ln2
$$
finally giving
$$
y = e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2-x+\ln2} +2
$$
or equivalently,
$$
y = 2e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2-x} +2
$$